# PyCharm shows ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2' even though it has been installed successfully

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, pycharm, face-detection

I tried a course on Face Detection using OpenCV and I got stuck on the first step itself because after running the test code, PyCharm shows ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'. However I have installed OpenCV successfully using `pip install opencv-contrib-python` and my pip has been updated to the latest version.
I'm using Windows 10 (64 bits)
Python Version: 3.9.6
Numpy Version: 1.21.1
OpenCV Version: 4.5.3.56
Pip Version: 21.2.2
Code to print the 3D Matrix of a colored image:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\bibhr\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject2\\lfc.jpg",1)
print(img)
```

Error Message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

Image for `pip list`:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qghN.png)

**I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Python and OpenCV but none of that worked**
Any help would be appreciated as I need to finish this project in a couple of weeks.

Also, I couldn't find `cv2.so` file in *C:\Users\bibhr\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\cv2*

Is that the reason? If yes, then how do I find `cv2.so` in my computer? (The search box couldn't find it either)

Comment: are you using a virtual environment or the global python installation?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `pip install opencv-python` instead of `opencv-contrib-python`
Hope this will be helpful!

Comment: I did use ```pip install opencv-python``` in the beginning, but still it showed similar error. So I used ```pip install opencv-contrib-python``` the second time.

Comment: Have you installed `numpy`? https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d5/de5/tutorial_py_setup_in_windows.html and install Visual C++ Redistributable 2015 (https://pypi.org/project/opencv-contrib-python/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone. I solved the issue by changing the Project interpreter from Virtual Environment to Existing Interpreter.